# Can I get sound out of both iMac and attached Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: imac, audio, display

I have a dual monitor setup (iMac + Thunderbolt Display). The System Preferences > Sound > Output setup only allows me to choose between one or the other monitor. This causes the sound to come only from left or right side.

Any way to get both monitors to play audio simultaneously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the Audio MIDI Utility (a.k.a. Audio MIDI Setup on Mountain Lion) to create an Aggregate device to mix both output destinations into one item the OS can select.

The Help topics in OSX around this area are...

[Play audio through multiple output devices at once](https://help.apple.com/audiomidisetup/mac/10.7/help/index.html?lang=en#ams35796)

[Combine audio devices to use a single device](https://help.apple.com/audiomidisetup/mac/10.7/help/index.html?lang=en#ams1011)

Comment: I found this as well, but StackEx didn't let me answer my own question. ;) "Multi-Output Device" worked. Only problem is now the master volume buttons (F10, F11, F12) are disabled. If I need to change the volume or mute, I have to do it on the app (which is not always available) or go back into Audio Midi and change volume for each speaker. (Try muting really fast if the phone rings...). Any ideas?

Comment: I like the TakeFive app to rapidly pause iTunes for a phone call - not sure if it controls your player of choice, but it's awesome from the Iconfactory - on the app store too...

Comment: @Luciano Can you post more information about the exact settings? I tried using The Audio MIDI Utility, but I could not seem to figure out the right settings.

Comment: This works, however as the OP said you can't use the volume buttons.  You have to go back to the MIDI settings and change the volume for both displays.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible.

By creating an [aggregate device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3956), you can combine the audio interfaces of the dual Apple LED Cinema Displays into a single speaker.

Here's an overview of [the process](http://www.sethwebster.com/2012/07/18/mac-osx-lion-output-sound-to-multiple-devices/):

1. Open **/Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup**
2. Click <kbd>+</kbd> to add a new **Multiple Output Device**
3. Select one or more **Display Audio** devices
4. Adjust the volume slider for each **Apple LED Cinema Display**
5. Right click on the new "Multi-Output Device" and select "Use this device for sound output" and "Play alerts and sound effects through this device".

[image: Combining two Apple Displays for Audio Sound Output]

There is one caveat to this setup — you can't adjust the volume using either the keyboard shortcut or the speaker icon, as it appears disabled in the OS X Menu Bar<sup>[†](http://www.jeremyjohnstone.com/blog/2012-03-24-using-all-speakers-on-multiple-cinema-displays-in-mac-os-x.html)</sup>. you can <kbd>Option + Click</kbd> to toggle between audio output devices though.

[Sunflower](https://github.com/Cycling74/Soundflower) is an open source third-party app that will give you the volume control back, but since it's a kernel extension you should understand the implications before installing it.

Another software to use that isn't a kernel extension and can perfectly overcome the obstacle of not having control over your volume buttons is by using [Sound Control](https://staticz.com/soundcontrol/). It actually gives you back your volume control buttons on your keyboard. Plus it has a 14 day free trial.

Comment: What did you mean by option click between devices? I am trying to do this now.

Comment: I followed these instructions, and what I got was a 4 channel aggregate device, where because Spotify only delivers two channels all sound still comes out of my left monitor. What can I do to mix 2 channel stereo in to 4 channel, so that I can have all four speakers work?