# Can you play sound out of Macbook Pro & Apple Cinema Display Simultaneously

Tags: macos, audio, cinema-display, speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get sound out of both iMac and attached Thunderbolt Display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/can-i-get-sound-out-of-both-imac-and-attached-thunderbolt-display)

I have a macbook pro 2009 model, and a 24' apple cinema display.  When the USB is connected the audio switches from the built in speakers of the laptop to the speakers on the cinema display.

Is it possible to take advantage of both of these speakers at the same time?

Comment: You should have the exact same situation and solution as this other question. Feel free to edit in details that show your case isn't solved by the existing answer of using Audio MIDI to mix the two devices and select it. A flag will let us know to review this for re-opening if needed.